# How to pass parameters to a form from a class based View with Django 1.8?

Tags: python, django

excuse my english

I'd like to pass a parameter to the constructor of a form from a FormView. But, because when I use class based views, I'm not the one that create the form object so I am unable to do it this way .

I know maybe the best thing to would be to use a function view instead of a class based view, but does anyone know a way to do it using class based views ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say what type of class based view you are using, but anything that inherits from FormMixin has the method [`get_form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) for precisely this purpose.

Comment: Are you clear on how to override `get_form_kwargs` for your situation? It wouldn't be hard to put together an example if not.